# Element <option> could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select a value with Selenium.

This is the target **HTML**:

```
  <div class="main_table">
        <div class="fields filter_center clearfix" style="margin: 0 auto;">
            <div class="form-group clearfix">                    
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select class="form-control input-sm js-example-basic-single" name="city">
                                                            <option style="padding: 3px;" value="213">New York</option>
                                                            <option style="padding: 3px;" value="2">Washington</option>
                                                            <option style="padding: 3px;" value="47">Los Angeles</option>
```

My first attempt:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


region_element = Select(drv.find_element_by_tag_name("select"))
region_element.select_by_value("2")
```

This raises:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view
```

My attempt 2:

```
region_element = WebDriverWait(drv, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='city']")))
region_element = Select(region_element)
region_element.select_by_value("2")
```

Again:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view
```

Attempt 3 (wait for the specific option to be clickable):

```
region_element = WebDriverWait(drv, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='city']")))

WebDriverWait(drv, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='city']/option[text()='Washington']")))

region_element = Select(region_element)
region_element.select_by_value("2")
```

Again:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view
```

Could you help me correct the situation?

Comment: Try `print(len(drv.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@name='city']")))`. Does it return `1`?

Comment: Andersson, yes, it returns .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the option menu its not hidden inside a wrapper, example another dropdown menu or nested page try with actions moving to it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='city']")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

or with javascript executor

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```